# How to use Neo4j APOC method " apoc.export.csv.query(query,file,config)" in Java program

Tags: java, neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

How can I use this cypher query using APOC in Java program?

```
CALL apoc.export.csv.query("match (m:Movie) where m.name='Matrix'
RETURN m.name","results.csv",{})
```

If any one can refer/suggest to sample JAVA code, it would be great. A few lines or one line code, I shall a thankful.

Following is my Sample code which is giving error at line:

```
StatementResult result = session.run("CALL apoc.export.csv.query("match (m:Movie) where m.name='Matrix' return m.name","results.csv",{})");

/////

public class bolt {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Driver driver = GraphDatabase.driver("bolt://127.0.0.1:7687", AuthTokens.basic("neo4j", "neo4j"));
        Session session = driver.session();
        StatementResult result = session.run("CALL apoc.export.csv.query("match (m:Movie) where m.name='Matrix' return m.name","results.csv",{})");

        session.close();
        driver.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: Just escape the quotation characters inside the string: `"CALL apoc.export.csv.query(\"match ...`

Comment: Thanks Bruno. It worked by changing the code as:
StatementResult result = session.run("CALL apoc.export.csv.query(\"match (m:Person) return m.name\",\"results.csv\",{})");

Comment: I added the answer so that you can accept/upvote is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just escape the quotation characters inside the string.

```
StatementResult result = session.run(
    "CALL apoc.export.csv.query(\"match (m:Movie) where m.name='Matrix' return m.name\",\"results.csv\",{})"
);
```